# Functions is not deployed correctly with an error saying that 'could not find a valid build'

Tags: reactjs, next.js

As the title says, currently I am unable to deploy functions from my terminal. I want to deploy functions as normal. It seems Next comes in the way.

My project folder directory structure is as follows:

```
- root 
  - dist 
  - src 
     - app
     - functions <- I only want to deploy this folder to Cloud Functions
     - public
  - node_modules
  - package.json 
  - jest.config.js
  - firebaserc

  And other setting files are managed here
```

This is firebase.json

```
{
  ....

  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm run lint",
      "npm run build"
    ],
    "source": "."
  },

  ...
}
```

This is my package.json

```
{
"name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development next src/app",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "build:app": "npm run clean && NODE_ENV=development next build src/app",
    "build:app:prod": "npm run clean && NODE_ENV=production next build src/app",
    "start:app": "next start src/app",
    "lint": "tslint --project src/functions/tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc --project src/functions",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions,hosting",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "npm run build && firebase deploy --only functions",
    "deploy:hosting": "firebase deploy --only functions:hosting",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
"main": "dist/functions/index.js",
"dependencies": {.....}
}
```

This is what the error message in the console below says while executing script:

```
Running command: npm run build

> functions@ build /Users/{user}/Desktop/{project}
> tsc --project src/functions

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing . directory for uploading...

Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

Error: Could not find a valid build in the '/Users/{user}/Desktop/{project}/dist/functions/next' directory! Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the server.
```

I have no idea why this error comes out? What am I doing wrong here? Is there any wrong with configuration/json files??

Comment: Have you used `next build` in build script? Can you show full package.json?

Comment: Updated the post. I basically used script of ```npm run deploy```. I do no use ```next build``` when I execute

Comment: Nextjs requires you to use `next build` as it creates a build version of your project and then you can deploy it.

Comment: Thank you for quick explanation. ```next build src/functions``` will make a build version in the dist folder and it then becomes deployable ?

Comment: Hitting ```next build src/functions ``` makes an error next ```Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root``` What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read the official nextjs [tutorial](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app) first.

You use nextjs so that your website pages are generated in server instead of in client, pre-render pages at build time (SSG) or request time (SSR), this is done mostly to make website SEO friendly. That's why you need pages directory in root which will have all pages.

Your scripts also needs to be modified, it should atleast have something like follows:

```
"scripts": { 
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start" 
},
```

This way when you do `npm build`, nextjs will build a "build version" of your project, which you can deploy later.

Comment: I want to deploy functions to Cloud Functions not the app itself though. Still does it require to do ```next build``` to get a build version of it?